# C#: is there a way to make generic constraint where T shorter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method looks like:

```
void Do<T>(T arg) where T: IDisposeable, ICloneable, IRunnable, IMyInterface1;
```

To make the generic constrain shorter, I tried use a new interface

```
interface ICombinedInterface: IDisposeable, ICloneable, IRunnable, IMyInterface1 {}

void Do<T>(T arg) where T: ICombinedInterface;
```

However, some third party libraries didnot and willnot implement my interface, so I cannot use their classes in my `Do<T>(T arg)` method.

Is there anyway to make the generic contraint shorter?

Comment: What you trying to achieve? To reduce line length you can put constraints on multiple lines.

Comment: you could argue that what you are asking to do makes the code less understandable and increases cognitive friction.

Comment: It sounds like your `Do` method is doing too much work if you need that many constraints.

Comment: If a marker interface is not working for you, then the answer is no. However, as other have   pondered, do you need all these constraints? if you do, you are out of luck again

Comment: @JesseGood I have several simple methods like `Do1<T1>, Do2<T2>,  Do3<T3>` and  `Do<T>`  calls all of them

Comment: You should refactor your code so that `Do<T>` doesn't have to call that many methods.